# Restore caret position when replacing editable div content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, replace, innerhtml

I have an editable div which allows tagging and on change the following code gets run to replace the innerHTML:

```
const setDisplayText = (element: HTMLDivElement) => {
   element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/<span style="color: (.*?)">/g, '')
   element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replaceAll('</span>', '')
   element.innerHTML = element?.innerHTML.replace(/\$(.*?)( |&nbsp;|$)/g, `<span style="color: ${colors.blue_light}">$$$1</span>&nbsp;`)
```

However, when I do this the caret keeps returning to the start. I found one solution but it ignores line breaks.

Has anyone had to do anything similar?

Comment: I have, unfortunately, had to do this sort of thing before. The solution is just to get the current caret position, and then move the caret back to that position afterwards.

Comment: However, if you have to do anything much more complicated, I'd recommend moving away from contenteditable entirely. The related APIs, having to deal with HTML, different browsers generating different HTML e.g. when you press enter, the range APIs, etc, are all horrible. You can get like 80% of the way there, and then there's parts that are just impossible. Counterintuitively, building WYSIWYG stuff yourself actually turns out better --- Google docs, for example, just renders the whole page to a canvas, caret and all. Otherwise, maybe look into something like prosemirror.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to use draft js